# Exponential extrapolation

Tags: optimization, regression, extrapolation

Given a set of points on 2D surface $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)$ and a function $f(x)=k+ab^x$, the task is to find values of $k,a$ and $b$ that minimize the following sum:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (k+ab^{x_i}-y_i)^2.$$

I tried to get derivatives (with respect to $k,a,b$) from this sum and got the system of three equations, but it's impossible for me to express unknowns from it. Also I'm looking for numerical answer.

Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks for the help.

Comment: It would help the readers if you posted the system of equations -- in fact, your problem might even have been errors in computing the system, and posting it would let us see.

Comment: Are you in a setting that expects a symbolic answer? Or are you in a setting where a numeric answer is sufficient? While I imagine it should be easy to eliminate $k$ and $a$ (aren't the equations *linear* in those variables?), just eyeballing the equation makes it look like you'll need a numeric solution for $k$ (Or familiarity with LambertW, I suppose). And even if a symbolic solution is possible, a numeric one might be easier.

Comment: @Hurkyl, yes I found $k$ and $a$ but $b$ is very hard to express. And I'm looking for numeric answer. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Did you try rewrite a equation like $\ln(y_i - k) = \ln a + x \ln b$? You can use simple regression in this case.

Comment: I haven't noticed $k$ is also variable... But that transformation may help.

Comment: If a numeric answer is fine, my first thought would be to try Newton's algorithm. Or simply use a binary search or plot the function and pick it out visually, depending on which one is easier to implement.

Comment: It's a least-squares fit; the standard method here is to use Levenberg-Marquardt, which you should look up.

Comment: @Taro thanks for your tip. It helped me to solve a task (see my answer).

Comment: @Taro, of course, linearization means that you're no longer doing a true least squares fit, since you're also transforming the errors in the data to something that might no longer have a normal distribution...

Comment: @J.M. Yes, it is. So estimating statistical values such as standard deviation might gets harder. Also the weight is different from least squares fit and therefore it gives different values from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **@Taro** hint to solve this task.

I made the following change:

$$\ A=lna\\
    B=lnb
$$

And rewritten the function:
$$\ ln(y_i-k)=A+x_iB
$$

After this I've got a system with 2 unknowns $A$ and $B$ ($k$ is parameter):

$$\begin{cases}
\sum_{i=1}^n ln(y_i-k)=nA+B\sum_{i=1}^nx_i \\
\sum_{i=1}^n ln(y_i-k)x_i=A\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+B\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2
\end{cases}$$

As you can see right part of system is static - only left part depends on $k$.

And solved it with binary search (used $k$ as parameter).

Here's a result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Gauss-Newton algorithm directly deals with this type of problems. Given m data points $(x_i,y_i)$  for regression with a function of n parameters $\vec \beta =(\beta_1,...,\beta_n)$ 
$$min_{\vec \beta }\ S(\vec \beta)\ where\ S(\vec \beta)=\sum_{i=1}^m r_i(\vec \beta)^2=(y_i-f(\vec \beta,x_i))^2$$
I skip the derivation of algorithm which you can find in every textbook (First use Taylor approximation and then use Newton's method). 
$$\Delta \vec \beta=\big(J^T\ J\big)^{-1}\ J^T\ \vec r$$
$$\vec \beta=\vec \beta + \alpha\ \Delta \beta$$
where $\alpha$ is damping coefficient and
$$J=\begin{pmatrix}\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \beta_1}\bigg)_{x=x_1}&...&\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \beta_n}\bigg)_{x=x_1}\\\ ...&...&...\\\ \bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \beta_1}\bigg)_{x=x_m}&...&\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \beta_n}\bigg)_{x=x_m}\end{pmatrix}\quad \vec r=\begin{pmatrix}y_1-f(\vec \beta,x_1)\\\ ... \\\ y_m-f(\vec \beta,x_m) \end{pmatrix}$$
For your specific case
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}=b^{x_i}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}=a\ b^{x_i-1}\ x_i$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}=1$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1), but I solved it in a different way (see my answer).

Comment: @ArtemStorozhuk you welcome. Thanks for notification

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to have to think too much, you can chuck your problem into some Gauss-Newton or Levenberg-Marquardt routine and be done with it. If you're willing to do a bit of analytical work, here's a way that might make for a less computationally-intensive solution.

You can ease your problem by recognizing that your model is **linear** in the parameters $a$ and $k$. In particular, taking partial derivatives of your objective function with respect to those two parameters and equating to zero results in the following set of **linear equations**:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\sum_j^n b^{2x_j}&\sum_j^n b^{x_j}\\\sum_j^n b^{x_j}&n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\k\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\sum_j^n y_j b^{x_j}\\\sum_j^n y_j\end{pmatrix}$$

which is easily solved with Gaussian elimination or Cramer's rule.

Now, taking the partial derivative with respect to the nonlinear parameter $b$ and equating to $0$ gives

$$\sum_j^n \left(x_j b^{x_j}\left(a b^{x_j}+k-y_j\right)\right)=0$$

Substituting the values of $a$ and $k$ obtained from the linear equations now yields **a nonlinear equation in the single unknown** $b$, which can then be solved with the standard methods like Newton-Raphson or Brent. Of course, you need a good guess for $b$; that's the part of the problem you will need to reckon out for yourself. Once you've obtained a nice value for $b$, you can then substitute it into your explicit expressions for $a$ and $k$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1), but I solved it in a different way (see my answer).